# System.ArgumentNullException when parsing Json in controller

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, .net-core

I'm new to C# and DotNet so I apologize if this is a pretty basic question.I am sending some Json through Postman to my application:

```
[
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Book",
    "price": 12.49,
    "import": false,
    "exempt": true
}]
```

I am returned this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.&#xD;&#xA;Parameter name: s&#xD;&#xA;   at System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s)&#xD;&#xA;   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)&#xD;&#xA;   at StoreFront.Controllers.StoreFrontController.Post(String product) in C:\Users\adamg\source\repos\StoreFront\StoreFront\Controllers\StoreFrontController.cs:line 43&#xD;&#xA;   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.&lt;InvokeActionMethodAsync&gt;d__12.MoveNext()&#xD;&#xA;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.&lt;InvokeNextActionFilterAsync&gt;d__10.MoveNext()&#xD;&#xA;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&amp; next, Scope&amp; scope, Object&amp; state, Boolean&amp; isCompleted)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.&lt;InvokeInnerFilterAsync&gt;d__14.MoveNext()&#xD;&#xA;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.&lt;InvokeNextResourceFilter&gt;d__22.MoveNext()&#xD;&#xA;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&amp; next, Scope&amp; scope, Object&amp; state, Boolean&amp; isCompleted)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.&lt;InvokeFilterPipelineAsync&gt;d__17.MoveNext()&#xD;&#xA;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__15.MoveNext()&#xD;&#xA;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.&lt;Invoke&gt;d__4.MoveNext()&#xD;&#xA;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.&lt;Invoke&gt;d__7.MoveNext()
```

Here is my controller Post method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string product)
    {
        JArray order = JArray.Parse(product);

        IList<Order> Order = order.Select(p => new Order
        {
            Total = (Double)p["Price"],

        }).ToList();

        _context.Order.Add(Order[0]);

        return Ok(order);
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `&#xD;&#xA;` is just a line break (=CR LF), if that helps the error message make more sense? Which is StoreFrontController line 43?

Comment: What's the class definition of Order? If you set a breakpoint in the 1st line of the Post method, can you confirm that the json string is correct?

Comment: Also, what's the version of ASP.NET MVC and .NET Framework you're using?

Comment: Hey, Oder is just an ID and a Double Total. I'm essentially just trying to Price from the Json object and make the order total at this point. I'll add more logic later. And I'm currently using .NET Core 2.

Comment: Can you post the value of the `product` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Framework 4.5.2 at least, following would work:

```
var expectedResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OrderDto>>(product);
```

assuming you had a class of:

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public bool import { get; set; }
    public bool exempt { get; set; }
}
```

hope that this applies to you as well.

Comment: Hey, I tried that earlier, but that doesn't seem to work in .NET Core 2 unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is case-sensitive.

```
Total = (Double)p["Price"],    // does not exist
Total = (Double)p["price"],    // ok
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried tinkering with the case, but that doesn't seem to help.